# Solution of a trigonometric inequality involving powers

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Given the following inequality:

$$\left(\cos(x^x)-\cos(x^y)\right)+\left(\cos(y^y)-\cos(y^x)\right)\gt0$$
how is it possible to find the values of $x,y$ for which the inequality is valid?
Thanks

Comment: The following inequality maybe useful  [$x^y+y^x>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381090/%24x%5Ey%2By%5Ex%3E1%24-for-all-%24%28x%2C-y%29%5Cin-%5Cmathbb%7Br_%2B%5E2%7D%24)

Comment: The solutions are symmetric. If $(a,b)$ is a solution, then $(b,a)$ is a solution, too, provided that $a\ne b$

Comment: Its a continuous map, so find where $\cos x^x + \cos y^y = \cos x^y + \cos y^x$. Points on one side of this curve will satisfy the inequality, while points on the other side will not.